# WPF, notify a child in the element tree about an event in a parent

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF app and I want an event in a parent to be notified to several of its children in the element tree, so that each of them can take an action accordingly. I know that a custom `RoutedEvent` can be used to signal in the other direction from a child to one of its ancestors by bubbling the event upwards, so that any of the ancestor elements can handle the event. What I want is the children to be notified about an event in the parent and they handle them appropriately. What is the best strategy to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Clarifying the comments : Say I have a parent `UserControl`. It has a `TabControl` and its contents are several nested child `UserControl`s. Now consider a scenario where I want the `TabControl.SelectionChanged()` event to cause some changes in each of the child `UserControl`. How to achieve this? (The contents of each tab is a `UserControl` which themselves may contain another few levels of children `UserControl`s. I want the `UserControl` in the bottom level to know about the `SelectionChanged()` event and respond accordingly).

Comment: Best strategy would be attached properties and attached events.

Comment: your question is not clear, headline states "notify a child of event in parent", body states "parent to be notified of children". Please clarify your question!

Comment: also please state if the event is data/model based or a pure UI event

Comment: @NickolaiNielsen Sorry if i was not clear..  I wrote " event in the parent to be notified to its children"

Comment: The event is a UI event, not data/model based,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways that your requirements could be implemented. If your parent view model has instances of the child view models, then you can simply call methods on them:

In parent view model:

```
childViewModel.UpdateStatus(someDataObject);
otherChildViewModel.UpdateStatus(someDataObject);
```

If you want a more event driven system, you can use `delegate`s:

```
public delegate void Update(object someDataObject);
```

Add a property of that type to the parent view model:

```
public Update OnUpdate { get; set; }
```

Attach handlers to each of the child views in the parent view model:

```
OnUpdate += childViewModel.OnUpdateHandler;
OnUpdate += otherChildViewModel.OnUpdateHandler;
```

Then call the `delegate` from the parent view model:

```
if (OnUpdate != null) OnUpdate(someDataObject);
```

If your parent view model does *not* have access to the child view model objects, then maybe you could add properties to the child views and then `Bind` to them from the parent view model:

```
<YourXmlNamespace:ChildView UpdateValue="{Binding DataContext.SomeDataObjectProperty, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type 
    YourXmlNamespace:ParentView}}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a databinding or trigger and listen for Ancestor TabControl.SelectedItem changed

Answer (score 0):

I think, this sample will help you:
http://akashsoni7.blogspot.com/2012/12/c-notify-parent-from-child-using-events.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try to bind some property in child element with TabItem's IsSelected, something simple like:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Second"/>
    <TabItem Name="firstTab" Header="First" >
        <StackPanel >
            <TextBox Height="30" Width="150" Name="tbx1" Text="{Binding ElementName=firstTab,Path=IsSelected}"/>
            <TextBox Height="30" Width="150" Name="tbx2" Text="{Binding ElementName=firstTab,Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey}}"/>
            <TextBox Height="30" Width="150" Name="tbx3" Text="{Binding ElementName=firstTab,Path=IsSelected}" TextChanged="tblk3_TextChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```